# Kern and Im of HOMOMORPHIS

Tags: linear-algebra

$${K^{n\times n}_{sym}=\{A \in K^{n\times n} \mid A^{tr}=A \}}$$ 
$${K^{n\times n}_{skew}=\{A \in K^{n\times n} \mid A^{tr}=-A \}}$$

(1)  I have to find out if there is $ m \in{N_0}$ and an injective  R-vectorsapceHomorphismus $\phi  :{R^m } \rightarrow {R^{2\times 2}}$
with $Im_{\phi}={R^{2\times 2}_{sym}}$ , if yes i must find its form

(2)  I have to find out if there a  R-vectorsapceHomorphismus $\phi  :{R^{2\times 2}} \rightarrow {R^{2\times 2}}$
with $Im_{\phi}\subseteq{R^{2\times 2}_{sym}}$  ,and$Kern_{\phi}\subseteq{R^{2\times 2}_{sym}}$ , if yes i must find its form

(3) I have to find out if there a  R-vectorsapceHomorphismus $\phi  :{R^{2\times 2}} \rightarrow {R^{2\times 2}}$
with $Im_{\phi}\subseteq{R^{n\times n}_{skew}}$  ,and$Kern_{\phi}\subseteq{R^{n\times n}_{skew}}$ , if yes i must find its form

$\textbf{My Idea}$

first  i did  determine the  base of ${R^{2\times 2}_{sym}}$ and ${R^{2\times 2}_{skew}}$

the base  of ${R^{2\times 2}_{sym}}$ is   ( $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end {bmatrix}$ ,$\begin{bmatrix} 1 &  0\\
0 & 0
\end {bmatrix}$,$\begin{bmatrix} 0 &  0\\
0 & 1
\end {bmatrix}$)

and the base of ${R^{2\times 2}_{skew}}$  is ( $\begin{bmatrix} 0 &  1\\
-1 & 0
\end {bmatrix}$)

$\textbf{my answer for the  (1) } $

i know that  $\phi$ is injective  $\Rightarrow   dim(Kern_{\phi}) =0 $

and $dim(R^{m}) = dim(Kern_{\phi})  + dim(Im_{\phi})  = m =0 +dim(Im_{\phi})$

and because $ Im_{\phi} ={R^{2\times 2}_{sym}}\Rightarrow dim(Im_{\phi}) = dim (R^{2\times 2}_{sym}) = 3 \Rightarrow  m = 3 $
then

$\phi : {R^3} \rightarrow {R^{2\times 2}} $, (a,b,c) $\mapsto a 
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 1 \\ 
1& 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}+ b \begin{bmatrix} 
1 &  0\\ 
0& 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}+c\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 0 \\ 
0& 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} $

$\textbf{my answer for the  (2) } $
$\phi : {R^{2\times 2}} \rightarrow {R^{2\times 2}}$

$\begin{bmatrix}
{a_{11}} & {a_{11}} \\ 
{a_{21}} & {a_{22}} \\ 
\end{bmatrix} \mapsto (a_{12}-a_{21}) \begin{bmatrix}
0 &1\\ 
1&0 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}+ (a_{12}-a_{21})\begin{bmatrix}
0 &0\\ 
0&1 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$

$\textbf{3}

here it is not possbile  because 
$ dim({R^{2\times 2}_{skew}}) =1$

$dim ({R^{2\times 2}})= 4 = dim(Kern_{\phi})  + dim(Im_{\phi})$ 
but $ dim(Kern_{\phi}) \leq 1$ and $dim(Im_{\phi}) \leq 1 $

$\textbf{Am i Correct ,  i guess there is something  wrong in 2, but please tell me if i am correct  }$